# How to define static mongoose methods in document interface while using @nestjs/mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

**Mongoose Schema Class** 
Mongoose collection user schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    enum: Object.keys(GenderType),
    required: true,
  },
});

UserSchema.methods = {

  fullName(): string {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  },

};

UserSchema.statics = {

  someAction(): string {
    return '123';
  },

};

export default UserSchema;
```

**Document Interface Class**

Mongoose collection interface class

```
export interface IUser extends Document {

  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  gender: string;

  fullName: () => string;
}
```

How to define static mongoose methods in document interface while using @nestjs/mongoose?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `IUser`, you might want to have an extra interface `IUserModel` and extends it from `Model<T>`. Sample snippet might look as follow:

```
export interface IUserModel extends Model<IUser> {
     // Model is imported from mongoose
     // you can put your statics methods here
     someAction: () => string;
}
```

Then in wherever you're injecting the Model using `@InjectModel()`, you can type your injection of type `IUserModel`.

```
constructor(@InjectModel('UserModel') private readonly userModel: IUserModel) {}
```

Now your `this.userModel` will have access to `someAction()` method.

Happy coding!